# XGboost validation immediately drops and becomes stationary

Tags: boosting, loss-functions, overfitting

[image: Training & validation loss curves]

I'm attempting to fit an xgboost model to some data. During training I'm seeing the RMSE for the validation set very quickly decrease, and then become basically static. The Validation performance is pretty poor and doesnt look to be converging. I'm not sure how to interpret this at all really. I've tuned the hyperparamters max_depth gamma, alpha, lambda and min_child_weight to try find an optimum set.

Could it be a sign my model is underfitting/ overfitting ? Essentially I would like to know 1) Why the loss drops so quickly and 2) Why it does it not improve or disimprove at all, I would expect a change for better or worse. Is it possible that I do not need the number of estimators I'm using ?